# Conditional pdf

Tags: probability

$f(x) = 2(1-x)$ for $0 <  x < 1$

Given that $X$ exceeds $0.5$ what is the probability that $X$ is less than $0.75$?

How do I go on about thia problem?
I can calculate the probability of exceeding $0.5$ by just taking the integral from $0.5$ to $1$ but I don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that $X\gt 0.5$ and $B$ be the event $X\lt 0.75$. You are asked for the probability of $B$ given $A$, in symbols $\Pr(B|A)$. By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(B|A)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}.$$

The two probabilities on the right can be evaluated by integrating. The top one is
$$\int_{0.5}^{0.75}2(1-x)\,dx.$$
You wrote down the integral for the bottom one.

Comment: What would be the 100th percentile? Would it be n(p) = 2p^(1/2)

Comment: The hundredth percentile is at the very top, $1$ in this case. Not very interesting! The $80$-th percentile would be the point $p$ such that $\int_0^p 2(1-x)\,dx=0.8$.